# If Statement for reduction of a 9-bit to 5-bit binary number

Tags: vhdl

How can I use the "if statement"?

I have a 9-bit number. I need to check the MSB. If the MSB is "1" then I have to do the XOR operation with "100101" (reduction polynomial).

If the MSB is zero then I have skip the bit.

My main aim is to reduce the 9-bit number to 5-bit.

For example:
Here m = 5

Loop 1 (2m-2 = 8)
101010100 (MSB is the 9th bit)

### 100101

x01111100

MSB = 1 (true), XOR with reduction polynomial.
Result: 01111100 (8 bit result, removed the 9th bit)

Loop 2 (7)
01111100 (MSB is the 8th bit)

### 100101

MSB = 0 (false), skip and end the loop.
Result: 01111100 (still 8 bit result, but we are not using the MSB for the next loop)

Loop 3 (6)
1111100 (MSB is the 7th bit)

### 100101

x110110

MSB = 1 (true), XOR with reduction polynomial.
Result: 0110110 (7 bit result)

Loop 4 (m = 5)
110110 (MSB is the 6th bit)

### 100101

x10011 (Final result)

MSB = 1 (true), XOR with reduction polynomial.
Final result: 010011 (6 bit result, but we can discard the MSB)

Could you please give me some idea about it?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know next to nothing about VHDL, but it looks like you're trying to implement something like a [Galois LFSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register#Galois_LFSRs) or, more generally, [reduction modulo a polynomial in GF(2<sup>n</sup>)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field_arithmetic).

If so, you don't need to use an "if statement" for this.
Instead, just extract the MSB of you number and XOR it with each of the bits in the rest of the number that are set in your reduction polynomial.

If the MSB is set, this is equivalent to XORing your number with the reduction polynomial; if it's unset, then nothing happens, since XORing a bit with 0 does nothing.

Comment: I am working for the implementation of Galois field,the squaring part.If I take a 5-bit number like 11111 and do the square of it (do XOR operation while adding, not the simple binary operation) then I will get 101010101.So in general if the input is a= a4a3a2a1a0 then we will get the result of squaring by adding zeros in the middle of the bits.so the output is "a4-0-a3-0-a2-0-a1-0-a0".I need to reduce it to 5-bit by using reduction polynomial x^5+x^2+1 by above pattern.I have been able to add zeros but then I do not understand how to reduce.Can you please help me to do that part for 5-bit?

Answer (score 1):

if you have a `std_logic_vector` (let's call it `v`) you can check any particular bit of it using:

```
if v(5) = '1' then

end if;
```

For checking MSBs and LSBs you can use the built in attributes `'left` and `'right`.  For example:

```
if v'left = '1' then -- check the MSB
```